# Exception thrown is null

Tags: java, exception

I have a setup such as...

```
public class MyClass {
   Exception e = null;   

   try {
      Game.runItNow();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      this.e = e;
   }

   if (this.e == null) {
      showError();
   }
}

public class Game {
    public static void runItNow() throws IOException {
       try {
          HttpManager.getData()
       } catch(IOException e) {
          // here, e = null
          throw e;
       }
    }
}

public class HttpManager {    

    public static String getData() throws IOException {
       String someData = "The fox is brown";
       String someWord = "fox";

       if (someData.contains(someWord)) {
          throw new IOException();
       }

       return someData;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I catch the IO exception..`e == null`. Not sure if I'm having a brain fart or not, but I'm pretty confused. Why is `e == null`? I am throwing a new instance of it.

Comment: How did you verify that `e` is null?

Comment: Using the debugger, and also in the UI layer there is an `if` statement which checks if `e` is null.

Comment: You might be referring to e.getMessage() which may be null because no message is there while throwing exception

Comment: could you post a reproducible ideone demo for the same?

Comment: most of the time when I get things like this is when the class files are not in sync with the source (e.g. errors in the compile etc).

Comment: Your code is not even compiled. `getData()` needs to have a `return`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, sorry. Typo.

Comment: Can you post the code from the UI layer?

Comment: It is definitely not null, either it is a mistake by you or a bug in the IDE (I doubt the latter). Which IDE are you using? Can you post the condition of the breakpoint? (Moreover you need a throws declaration in the `runItNow` method).

Comment: In the actual code, there is a throws declaration - a mistake on my part copying it over. I'm using Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Whats `MyClass` you have code that isnt in static blocks, a constructor or a method.

Comment: OP, are you seriously saying that Java **catches a `null` exception**? That is **definitely, not in a million years**, what is really happening to your app.

Comment: That code does not compile. Ergo you are not running that code.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you have above is what you actually have then it's no wonder it isn't working.  Your `MyClass` isn't a proper class.  Either you need static blocks, a main method, or a constructor with that code in.

If you create a constructor with that code in, or a main method then it will work just fine.

```
public class MyClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Exception e = null;   

       try {
          Game.runItNow();
       } catch (Exception e) {
          this.e = e;
       }

       if (this.e == null) {
          showError();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you are overwriting the IOException generated with a new IOException without the exception.

Comment: Does not explain why `e` would be `null`.